# What does "carte" mean in this context?

Tags: education, legal-terms

> Neither position carried the day. On the one hand, this Court rejected the view that the IDEA gives “courts **carte** various judgments indicate should be imposed.” Rowley, 458 U. S., at 190, n. 11.

Source: https://www.creativeleadership.net/blog/2017/4/2/special-education-services-just-got-easier-and-harder-the-endrew-f-supreme-court-decision-in-the-courts-own-words

What does *carte* mean in this context?  What does the part in double quotes mean?  I tried two legal dictionaries and didn't find it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's supposed to be *carte blanche*, i.e. "blank check".  The quotation has left out several words.  You can find the full decision at https://supreme.justia.com/cases/federal/us/458/176/case.html.  The complete sentence is:

> It thus seems that the dissent would give the courts carte blanche to impose upon the States whatever burden their various judgments indicate should be imposed.

Comment: That makes so much more sense.  Here I was thinking it was another of those legal terms that looks like a garden variety word, but then it turns out to mean something special.